# CDK + ELB stuck forever

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

I try to create any ELB (Fargate or EC2) using CDK. But my attempts get stuck forever. For instance, this code also gets stuck:

```js
const vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, 'backoffice-vpc', {
      cidr: '10.0.0.0/16',
      natGateways: 0,
      maxAzs: 3,
      subnetConfiguration: [
        {
          name: 'public-subnet-1',
          subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
          cidrMask: 24,
        },
        {
          name: 'isolated-subnet-1',
          subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED,
          cidrMask: 28,
        },
      ],
    });

    // create a security group for the EC2 instance
    const ec2InstanceSG = new ec2.SecurityGroup(this, 'ec2-backoffice-sg', {
      vpc,
    });

    ec2InstanceSG.addIngressRule(
        ec2.Peer.anyIpv4(),
        ec2.Port.tcp(22),
        'allow SSH connections from anywhere',
    );

    const repository = ecr.Repository.fromRepositoryName(this, "tq-backoffice-repo",
        "tq-backoffice-repo")

    const cluster = new ecs.Cluster(this, "backoffice-cluster", {
      vpc,
      clusterName: 'backoffice-cluster',
    });

    cluster.addCapacity('DefaultAutoScalingGroupCapacity', {
      instanceType: ec2.InstanceType.of(
          ec2.InstanceClass.T2,
          ec2.InstanceSize.LARGE,
      ),
    });


    // Create a Fargate container image
    const image = ecs.ContainerImage.fromRegistry('amazon/amazon-ecs-sample');

    const taskDefinition = new TaskDefinition(this, 'Task', {
      compatibility: Compatibility.EC2,
      memoryMiB: '512',
      cpu: '256',
    });

    taskDefinition
        .addContainer('cms-img', {
          image: image,
          memoryLimitMiB:256,
          cpu: 256,
        })
        .addPortMappings({ containerPort: 1337 });

    cluster.addCapacity('app-scaling-group', {
      instanceType: new ec2.InstanceType('t2.micro'),
      desiredCapacity: 1,
      maxCapacity: 4,
      minCapacity: 1
    });

    new ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedEc2Service(
        this,
        'app-service',
        {
          cluster,
          cpu: 256,
          desiredCount: 1,
          minHealthyPercent: 50,
          maxHealthyPercent: 300,
          serviceName: 'cmsservice',
          taskDefinition: taskDefinition,
          publicLoadBalancer: true,
        },
    );
```

Last output from the `cdk deploy` is:

```
[20:15:50] Stack BackOfficeDeployStack has an ongoing operation in progress and is not stable (UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS)
[20:15:56] Stack BackOfficeDeployStack has an ongoing operation in progress and is not stable (UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS)
[20:16:01] Stack BackOfficeDeployStack has an ongoing operation in progress and is not stable (UPDATE_IN_PROGRESS)
```

In CloudFormation in progress next resource:

```
arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:273080356284:service/backoffice-cluster/cmsservice
```

Comment: What resource is it stuck on? You can check the cloudformation UI.

Comment: In progress resource with next ARN: arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:273080356284:service/backoffice-cluster/cmsservice

Comment: If you view the service in ECS, does that show an issue?

Comment: sorry, but no. I played earlier with different configs. Tried to find reason using CloudFormation, CloudTrail etc. I fight with the issue almost 1.5d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is `natGateway: 0`.  Your EC2 instances cannot communicate with ECR and ECS.

The solution is to either (a) configure a [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html) or (b) set up [VPC endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/aws-privatelink/what-are-vpc-endpoints.html) between your VPC and the dependent services.

This [AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/setting-up-aws-privatelink-for-amazon-ecs-and-amazon-ecr/) is helpful if you take the VPC endpoint route. You can add an Interface endpoint in the CDK like this:

```js
vpc.addInterfaceEndpoint("EcsVpcEndpoint", {
    service: ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.ECS,
    securityGroups: [securityGroup],
});
```

A note on cost:  While Interface Endpoints are *individually* cheaper ([$0.01/hr](https://aws.amazon.com/privatelink/pricing/)) than NAT Gateways ([$0.045/hr](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/pricing/)), you need several to work with EC2 ECS.  A NAT Gateway will end up being cheaper for this use case.

Comment: you are right, the first problem was with NAT. The second problem with my Docker image that has been created on Apple M1 machine and couldn't be started in ECS. Thanks.